# Is the reflexive needed in this case?

Tags: reflexivos

> I like to stay at home

Is it:

> Me gusta quedar en casa

or

> Me gusta quedarme en casa

Answer (score 2):

Your second option is the right one. *Quedarse* is a pronominal verb because the pronoun "se" doesn't carry out any syntactic function, it always agrees with the subject, and it's necessary for all the conjugation forms of the verb. Moreover, the meaning of the verb changes when a pronoun is added:

- Quedan tres huéspedes = There are three guests left // Three guests remain.
- **Se** quedan tres huéspedes = Three guests are staying.

There are other meanings (*quedar bien* = te leave a good impression; *quedarse sin tiempo* = to run out of time, etc.), but those are tangential to the question. However, one relevant meaning is "quedar" in the sense of "to meet". From [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=quedar):

> Mi hija y sus amigas quedaron a las seis en el cine = My daughter and her friends arranged (or: planned) to meet at the cinema at 6 o'clock.

If what you intended to say is "I like to meet [my friends] at home" or "I like to hang out at home", then "Me gusta quedar en casa" is fine. If what you mean is "I like to stay at home", only "Me gusta quedar**me** en casa" is correct.

Comment: The same happens with *gustar*. If we remove the object pronoun *me* in the sentence *me gusta bañarme*, it's not clear what you are addressing to: *me gusta bañar* (¿algo o alguien?) / *me gusta bañarme* (*bañarme a mí* en este caso)

Comment: @Ustanak, I do not agree with you -- The *me* you omitted has to do with `bañar`, not to do with `gustar`